# Is there a risk of storing a user's Android device ID in the database?

Tags: android, deviceid, android-identifiers

Can a person who somehow gains access to the database do something with this android device id? Is it possible to get any personal data via this id or something else? Or is it ok to store this id in the database?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for unique identifiers, device ID is no longer accessible as of Android 10.

There are a few options here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids